# Can the integration of $x^2$ be diagramed to show it's $\frac{x^3}{3}$?

Tags: integration, visualization

It's visually easy to see how the integral of a constant is $x=y$ as the area is growing linearly as you sum the dx boxes.

Similarly the integral for $y=x$ is $\frac{x^2}{2}$ which is the triangle formed by dissecting the ${x}$ x ${y}$ area.

But I'm not able to visualize the integer of $x^2$ as $\frac{x^3}{3}$.

I imagine a square extruded in the 3D axis but I can't see there the $\frac{1}{3}$ is coming from.

I tried to draw it but no help. Is there a visual trick to this?

It would be helpful to show this in a video I'm making about cross vs. dot product.

Answer (score 3):

For any $r > 0$, consider the cube $[0,r] \times [0,r]\times[0,r]$.
This cube has $3$ faces opposite to the the origin:
$$\{r\}\times[0,r]\times[0,r],\quad [0,r]\times \{r\}\times[0,r]\quad\text{ and }\quad [0,r]\times[0,r]\times\{r\}$$
Using origin as apex and these 3 faces as bases, we can decompose the cube into $3$ pyramids. These pyramid clearly have same volume. This mean the volume of each pyramid is $\frac13 r^3$.

Let's look at the first pyramid, if we intersect it with a plane
$x = t$ for $t \in [0,r]$, we get $\{t\} \times [0,t] \times [0,t]$, a square of side $t$. This means we can rewrite $\frac13 r^3$, the volume of first pyramid, as an integral. The end result is

$$\int_0^r x^2 dx = \frac13 r^3$$

Comment: Ahh!,,,Excellent...thank you.

... With cool variations here...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pBigy5Cwo8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LU-WMwlWfX0

... my work is complete! (till I press Save Edits.)